# need the react native app to receive headset button event when the device is in locked state

Tags: react-native, background, event-listener

How to run react native app in background. I need the app to accept the voice command when i click the headset button even when the device is in locked state.

Basically headset button click event should trigger the app to listen for voice. Currently my app accepting the voice command in foreground mode and works. but my requirement is even if device is locked , up on clicking the head set button i should trigger the app.

Comment: This is pretty tricky, borderline impossible I would say. While iOS is insanely strict, both iOS and Android terminate apps in the long run if they run in the background. I'm not sure about the exact rules for Android, but on iOS after the app was last opened you have 60 seconds until it's terminated. And it's only allowed to do background activity if it plays music. So you first want to read up on the respective native background rules.

Comment: can we do this while app is in foreground . and if it is possible suggest me source or way to do this because I am also working on such product where I need to interact my app with headphone button events thanks !

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't done before but today you can by adding some libraries to create a background service. I believe you can later capture the event you want. this what you will tell us.

Follow this [link](https://hackernoon.com/easy-os-background-tasks-in-react-native-bc4476c48b8a) to learn how to create the background service

Libraries you will need:

1. [React Native Queue](https://github.com/billmalarky/react-native-queue)
2. [react-native-background-task](https://github.com/jamesisaac/react-native-background-task)